# Storyboard: Connect IBOutlet to a ViewModel/Model bypassing the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, interface-builder, iboutlet

I have a rather complex form designed in the Interface Builder, having about 20 `IBOutlets`. The form is split onto multiple sections and is static.

Some of the sections might be enabled while the others are disabled (hidden). After the form has been filled in, the app needs to read all of the values (i.e. `IBOutlets` such as `UITextField`) and send them to the server.

I used multiple `UIStackViews` to design each section of the form, so that they could be easily switched on or off.

It's logical after having such a separation with views to have a model that would reflect the same order.

However, I had to link all of the `IBOutlets` to the `UIViewController` subclass, flattening any hierarchy.

What I'm trying to achieve is to link individual Form Section Model with specific View. The controller will be responsible only for enabling/disabling the section. The Form Section Model would actually enable specific labels and StackViews and fill in the form values.

Here is the example code I'd like the interface to look like:

```
import UIKit


class AddressSection {
    @IBOutlet weak var sectionStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sectionTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var isPrimary: UISwitch!
    var isHidden: Bool {
        get {
            return sectionStackView.isHidden
        }
        set(newValue) {
            sectionStackView.isHidden = newValue
        }
    }
    init(){}
}

class NameSection {
    @IBOutlet weak var sectionStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var surname: UITextField!
    var isHidden: Bool {
        get {
            return sectionStackView.isHidden
        }
        set(newValue) {
            sectionStackView.isHidden = newValue
        }
    }
    init(){}
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let name = NameSection()
    let address = AddressSection()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        name.isHidden = false
        address.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do it that way. One approach, though, would be to create custom `UIView` subclasses, connected to XIB files, with the IBOutlets connected inside those classes.

Comment: You might want to watch [Dave DeLong's talk about “A Better MVC”](https://vimeo.com/291601827).

Comment: Use code is totally under control.

Comment: @DonMag I was able to accomplish exactly what I wanted. Interestingly enough, the interface I'm using now is identical what I've prototyped in this question. I'm planning to post my answer soon.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks for the recommendation, interesting talk & sample app